# spritekit collisionBitMask pass through each other

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have two nodes - rabbit and slab. How can I get it pass through each other, and what I'm doing wrong?

```
static const uint32_t rabbitCategory = 0x1 << 1;
static const uint32_t slabCategory = 0x1 << 2;

rabbit.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = rabbitCategory;
rabbit.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = rabbitCategory;
slab.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = slabCategory;
slab.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = slabCategory;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
rabbit.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = rabbitCategory;
rabbit.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = borderCategory;

slab.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = slabCategory;
slab.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = slabCategory;
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to set the `collisionBitMask` to the category which the physics body will collide:

```
rabbit.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = rabbitCategory;
rabbit.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = slabCategory;
slab.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = slabCategory;
slab.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = rabbitCategory;
```